# Throw exception outside try block, nodeJS,JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, try-catch, block

Is it possible to throw an exception outside a `try` block? If I'm not mistaken in `Java` you can declare that a function `throws` an exception and then just throw it up the function chain, with no `try/catch` inside the function. Any similar method in `nodeJS`?

Also, I noticed that if I try to throw an exception from a callback function to where It was called in my code, I can't do it. I understand it can be solved using `domains`, which I still don't know. Am I right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you can throw exception from Anywhere:

Read [MDN:throw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Statements#throw_Statement)

For better understanding of error handling, [see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference) and search "error constructor"

Comment: There is no "javascript". The documentation of one ECMAScript implementation (here: Mozilla JavaScript) is usually not helpful in solving a problem with another one (here: Google V8 JavaScript).

Comment: @PointedEars: Have you checked the links? Are you sure that the pointed documents don't help the OP in understanding error handling? OP is interested in understanding error handling in Javascript (colloquial)

Comment: The OP is asking about node.js and need to get their basics right first. The question should have never been asked as it is.